# CSS3 Border issue when displaying my web page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when displaying my web page I'm using CSS border and margin in my code, but the output in my browser is very awkward this is my code and this is the output :

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD ; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 10px solid red; 
    margin: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Product title</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The output of my code in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVTEp.png)

Comment: What are you looking for? What are your expectations? Recommending you to look on the box model of second box to get an idea where it is coming from.

Comment: The code in your example doesn't match the image

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a second `div` element after the first one.

It might also be [Tag soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), you could try to validate your HTML and see if you have any errors or warnings.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD ; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 10px solid red; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>Product title</h1>
   <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div><div>
```

Comment: No, I have one div

Comment: When you right click on the second rectangle and `Inspect` the Element, what do you see in the DOM Inspector?

Comment: For me the second div is not coming on the browser, please have a look at your code. I copied your code only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you have 2 div tags after I see the results of your code. For my solution, you can create a card attribute as a product container like this:

```css
.card {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD ; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 10px solid red; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <h1>Product title</h1>
   <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to run it on anyother browsers as your code is seems fine there is no problem in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).